# Как достать все определенные объекты в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой массив:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    title: "coffe",
    price: 500
  },
  {
    title: "borsh",
    price: 700
  },
  {
    title: "fish",
    price: 150
  },
  {
    title: "tea",
    price: 80
  }
]
```

Мне нужно получить все объекты с название `price` и получить их сумму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```
let result = arr.reduce((acc, element) => (acc += element.price, acc), 0)
```

Comment: а зачем там скобки и в конце `, acc`?